# correlation matrix problems

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

Good afternoon,
I am a beginner of **Rstudio**, and I need to make a correlation matrix for this I have used:

```
cor (final_base, method = "pearson")
```

but since I get many NA variables in the array, I have tried to put:

```
cor (final_base, method = "pearson", na.rm = TRUE)
```

So that I do not count such data in the matrix, but that's when I get an error that says:

```
unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

How can I do to make the matrix, but without taking into account the NA of my database?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because `na.rm` is not a valid argument for the `cor` function. Use the argument `use` instead, which is "an optional character string giving a method for computing covariances in the presence of missing values." In your case, you can set this to `"complete.obs"`, as in:

```r
cor(final_base, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor).

Also, check out [this](http://bwlewis.github.io/covar/missing.html) note on the confusing (and therefore discouraged) `"pairwise.complete.obs"` option and whether to exclude missing values from correlation matrices in the first place. Instead, consider being explicit about these missings:

> If you want to run correlations on lots of vectors with missing values, consider simply using the R default of `use = "everything"` and propagating missing values into the correlation matrix. This makes it clear what you don’t know.